# Como editar o simple_form para personalizar os campos

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

gostaria de saber como faço para editar os campos dos forms com o simple_form, editar tal com o bootstrap, eu li uns tutoriais mas não entendi bem como faço para editar, como usar o class: 'form-control', etc.

```
<%= simple_form_for @admin_category, as: 'user_basic' do |f| %>
  <%= f.input  :name, label: 'Nome' %>
  <%= f.input  :active, as: :check_boxes, label: 'Ativo' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Este código é de um formulário simples em que eu gostaria que ele estivesse tal como os campos do bootstrap, mas aparece todo disconfigurado. 
Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o `input_html: { class: 'form-control' }` no seu input

```
<%= simple_form_for @admin_category, as: 'user_basic' do |f| %>
  <%= f.input  :name, label: 'Nome', input_html: { class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Nome" } %>
  <%= f.input  :active, as: :check_boxes, label: 'Ativo' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```